# How would you rig this hair?

Tags: rigging

I made this hair model using the curves system for my character izakaru. I tried using scripts to make each curve a bone for the mesh, but even that didn't work. I then tried making a rig by hand, and I can't seem to hit that sweet spot. How would I do that for this?

[image: this hair]

File with hair: https://www.mediafire.com/file/953mo3ubr81m4i5/Hair_Blend_Exchange.blend/file

Comment: Next time, please include a screenshot so we know what *this hair* looks like and better understand what you're talking about without having to download the blend file. -- What exactly didn't work?

Comment: you could assign a cloth simulation to your hair, but if you need bones, just create a series of vertical bone chains and parent With Automatic Weights?

Comment: That’s what I tried to do, but it didn’t work out.